# How do I access notes in mail.app in mac os x?

Tags: cocoa, syncservices

What I want to do here is sync notes in my app with notes in mail.app?
How can I access them?

With the sync service?

Any samples there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a fairly simple Sync Services client that syncs the com.apple.Notes schema - there isn't very much to it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SyncServicesSchemaRef/Articles/Notes.html

I don't believe there are notes sync samples floating around, but the enhanced Simple Stickies sample using ISyncSessionDriver could probably get you going in a couple of hours. Good luck.